# Store datapoints persistently before writing to database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, influxdb, wal

I have a Django app that receives sensor data. This data is then processed and written to `influxDB` using the `influxdb-client-python` library. I would like to write the data in an asynchronous manner and thus return a response to the producer of the data before it is actually written to the database.

However, once I send this response I can no longer afford to lose this data. Since I can never be sure that the server will in fact be able to write the data to `influxDB`, I was thinking about first writing it to a file and returning a response after this is successful (similar to a WAL). This introduces new problems like making sure the WAL is actually written to a file and most importantly, making sure it is thread-safe since the server may be handling multiple requests concurrently.

Is there any better way of doing this, maybe built-in in `Django`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a queue, background tasks, etc.  You are right, it just displaces the issue, but queues are highly reliable as well.

The standard libs for doing this with Django and/or Rest Framework are:

- [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/) - Full featured, mature, pluggable queue backends
- [Django RQ](https://github.com/rq/django-rq#django-rq) - Simpler, uses **only** redis

Celery is probably the right starting point here, since it lets you use a "real" queue backend, but Django RQ+redis will also work if there isn't a ton of load.

Without knowing anything more about your app or architecture, its hard to say more.  There are a lot of queuing systems ([Rabbit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/), AWS SQS, Google's, etc).  You can also look into building the queue+processor using, for example, AWS SQS and AWS Lambda Functions (or google versions).